# How to put sorted array from perl back into shell

Tags: arrays, bash, perl, shell, sorting

I have been working on a shell program that asks for a name of a file you wish to work with; then with one of the selections, sort it using a perl program. I got the shell program to the file into perl, and sorted the file. But now I am stuck as to put the file back to shell and save it into a new file. This is what I tried:

Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(MYINPUTFILE, $filename); # open for input
my (@lines) = <MYINPUTFILE>; # read file into list
@lines = sort(@lines); # sort the list
my ($line);
foreach $line (@lines) # loop thru list
 {
    print "$line"; # print in sort order
 }
close(MYINPUTFILE);
```

This prints the sorted list.

Just for reference this code is taking a file from the shell script and working with it. Here is that code

Shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
printf "Hello. \nPlease input a filename for a file containing a list of words you would like to use.  Please allow for one word per line.\n -> "
read filename
printf "You have entered the filename: $filename.\n"

if [ -f "$filename" ] #check if the file even exists in the current directory to use
then
    printf "The file $filename exists.  What would you like to do with this file?\n\n"
else
    printf "The file: $filename, does not exist.  Rerun this shell script and please enter a valid file with it's proper file extension.  An example of this would be mywords.txt \n\nNow exiting.\n\n"
    exit
fi

printf "Main Menu\n"
printf "=========\n"
printf "Select 1 to sort file using Shell and output to a new file.\n"
printf "Select 2 to sort file using Perl and output to a new file.\n"
printf "Select 3 to search for a word using Perl.\n"
printf "Select 4 to exit.\n\n"

echo "Please enter your selection below"
read selection
printf "You have selected option $selection.\n"

if [ $selection -eq "1" ]
then
    read -p "What would you like to call the new file? "  newfile   #asks user what they want to call the new file that will have the sorted list outputted to it
    sort $filename > $newfile
    echo "Your file: $newfile, has been created."
fi

if [ $selection -eq "2" ]
then
    read -p "What would you like to call the new file? "  newfile2
    perl sort.pl $filename
    # > $newfile2   #put the sorted list into the new output file that the user specificed with newfile2
fi

if [ $selection -eq "3" ]
then
    perl search.pl $filename
fi

if [ $selection -eq "4" ]
then
    printf "Now exiting.\n\n"
    exit
fi
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Does `perl sort.pl $filename > $newfile2` not work for you?

Comment: Thanks! This works!!!!!! Love each and everyone of you!

Comment: You know your entire script could be written in one line? `print sort <>;`

Comment: Which script are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments (but moved here to answer form):

Your Perl script outputs the results on STDOUT which means that the calling shell script can redirect it to an output file.  You'll use something similar to your option #1.

Change:

```
perl sort.pl $filename
```

To:

```
perl sort.pl $filename > $newfile2
```